# Convert Map<Employee, List<PersonalData>> to EmployeeDto with field List<PersonalDataDto> using mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

Как сконвертировать мапу в дто?
Есть мапа, вытянутая из репозитория: Map<Employee, List> map.
Есть сущность EmployeeDto с полями name, lastname и тд в том числе поле List.